# Accessing a protected member in a static method

Tags: c++, touchgfx

I have a circle of varying width. I created a subclass that was inherited by Screen1ViewBase class, to access "circlewidth" in WidthChange.cpp. I could access the "circlewidth". But I couldn't call Change function in Screen1View.cpp, cause it wasn't static. I made Change function static but this time I couldn't access "circlewidth" and the other member of Screen1View.

```
#ifndef SCREEN1VIEWBASE_HPP
#define SCREEN1VIEWBASE_HPP

#include <gui/common/FrontendApplication.hpp>
#include <mvp/View.hpp>
#include <gui/screen1_screen/Screen1Presenter.hpp>
#include <touchgfx/widgets/Box.hpp>
#include <touchgfx/widgets/canvas/Circle.hpp>
#include <touchgfx/widgets/canvas/PainterRGB565.hpp>

class Screen1ViewBase : public touchgfx::View<Screen1Presenter>
{
public:
    Screen1ViewBase();
    virtual ~Screen1ViewBase() {}
    virtual void setupScreen();

protected:
    FrontendApplication& application() {
        return *static_cast<FrontendApplication*>(touchgfx::Application::getInstance());
    }

    /*
     * Member Declarations
     */
    touchgfx::Box __background;
    touchgfx::Box box1;
    touchgfx::Circle circlewidth;
    touchgfx::PainterRGB565 circlewidthPainter;

private:

    /*
     * Canvas Buffer Size
     */
    static const uint16_t CANVAS_BUFFER_SIZE = 7200;
    uint8_t canvasBuffer[CANVAS_BUFFER_SIZE];
};

#endif // SCREEN1VIEWBASE_HPP
```

```
#ifndef SCREEN1VIEW_HPP
#define SCREEN1VIEW_HPP

#include <gui_generated/screen1_screen/Screen1ViewBase.hpp>
#include <gui/screen1_screen/Screen1Presenter.hpp>

class Screen1View : public Screen1ViewBase
{
public:
    Screen1View();
    virtual ~Screen1View() {}
    virtual void setupScreen();
    virtual void tearDownScreen();
    virtual void handleTickEvent();
protected:
    int lineWidthLimit;
    float circleWidthChangeFactor;
};

#endif // SCREEN1VIEW_HPP
```

```
#include <gui/screen1_screen/Screen1View.hpp>
#include <gui/WidthChange.hpp>


Screen1View::Screen1View()
{

}

void Screen1View::setupScreen()
{
    Screen1ViewBase::setupScreen();
}

void Screen1View::tearDownScreen()
{
    Screen1ViewBase::tearDownScreen();
}
void Screen1View::handleTickEvent()
{
    WidthChange::Change();
}
```

This is my class declaration

```
#ifndef WIDTHCHANGE_HPP    
#define WIDTHCHANGE_HPP 

#include <gui/screen1_screen/Screen1View.hpp>
#include <gui_generated/screen1_screen/Screen1ViewBase.hpp>

class WidthChange : public Screen1View
{

public:

    static void Change();

};

#endif
```

This is where Change() funct is declared

```
#include <gui/WidthChange.hpp>
#include <gui_generated/screen1_screen/Screen1ViewBase.hpp>
#include <gui/screen1_screen/Screen1View.hpp>
#include <gui/screen1_screen/Screen1Presenter.hpp>

void WidthChange::Change()
{
    float currentRad;
    float lineWidth;
    
    circlewidth.invalidate();

    circlewidth.getRadius(currentRad);
    if (currentRad >= lineWidthLimit)
    {
        circleWidthChangeFactor = -0.25;
    }
    else if (currentRad<= 15)
    {
        circleWidthChangeFactor = 0.25;
    }
    currentRad = currentRad + circleWidthChangeFactor;

    circlewidth.setRadius(currentRad);
    circlewidth.getLineWidth(lineWidth);
    circlewidth.setLineWidth(lineWidth + 2 * (circleWidthChangeFactor * (-1)));

    circlewidth.invalidate();
    }
```

I know there are a lot of things about it but I wonder if there is a way to access whole Screen1View members and Screen1ViewBase members when the Change function is called.

Comment: The inheritance structure here doesn't make a lot of sense to me. Why is `WidthChange` an entire class inheriting from `Screen1View`? Are you sure it shouldn't just be a member function of `Screen1View` to change its width? Especially if it's supposed to happening in `handleTickEvent` so it's not like you even have the possibility of `Screen1View` objects that _don't_ support changing width.

Comment: If it is a member function of Screen1View then it can't be called without the object reference in Screen1View, right?

Comment: Yes. Because `circlewidth` and `circleWidthChangeFactor` and `lineWidthLimit` are all member variables, how is `Change` possibly supposed to work _without_ a specific `Screen1View` instance to act on?

Answer (score -1):

Static member functions in c++ can only access static member data, or other static member functions. Screen1View can access static functions.

Having an intermediary class like this can be a good idea if your callback needs to do some complex ui setup/calculations. But it doesn't make sense to create a subclass of Screen1View here because it's of type `View` which isn't what you want (also comes with a lot of baggage).

If you need access to the members in `Screen1View` you could define a class with non-static members and construct it with a pointer to the parent instead of using inheritance, but giving members that kind of access to their parent isn't really recommended.

What i suggest instead is to have more general functions in a class definition. e.g. (contrived example). This would allow you to keep a clear description of the code in your Views callback handlers instead of hiding it all away in some function in a helperclass. These functions could be static.

```cpp
void HelperClass::setCircleRadius(touchgfx::Circle* circle, float radius)
{  
  circle.setRadius(radius);
  circle.invalidate();
}
```

If we pretend that `CircleHelper` was more complete now your handler code in the View would look like this and be much more readable:

```cpp
void Screen1View::someCallback()
{
   CircleHelper::setRadius(&myCircle, someValue);
   //More calls here to do what you want. LineHelper::..
   //But now the code communicates only what it needs to.
   //Most often "invalidate" is expected, so we don't want to be
   //reading 100 occurrences of invalidate(); clutter
}
```

Before the TouchGFX Designer to generate ui code for you I've relied heavily on static helper classes to do tedious setup that usually just cluttered `setupScreen()` and provided no valuable information to anyone.